# Accessing arguments sent via npm run-script

Tags: node.js, npm

I run the command:

```
npm run a_script --oki="odo"
```

How do I get the value of `oki` in my script? I'd like to use it for example: `if(process.argv.oki === 'odo')`.

I tried:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

It doesn't show up there.

I read https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script and it doesn't give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to insert two dashes between the script name and the argument list for npm to pass them to your script.

e.g. `npm run a_script -- --oki="odo"`